# Symfony/Messenger no retry when critical exception from a web service

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-messenger

I try to use Symfony/Messenger with a web service. I don't understand why the queue don't retry 3 times when I have a critical error.

This is my messenger configuration:

```
framework:
    messenger:
        # Uncomment this (and the failed transport below) to send failed messages to this transport for later handling.
        # failure_transport: failed
        transports:
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transport-configuration
            # async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
            # failed: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'
            # sync: 'sync://'
            async_sms:
                dsn: 'doctrine://default?auto_setup=0&table_name=ec2_messenger_messages'
                options:
                    queue_name: 'async_sms'
                retry_strategy:
                    max_retries: 3
                    delay: 30000
                    multiplier: 2
                    max_delay: 0

        routing:
            # Route your messages to the transports
            # 'App\Message\YourMessage': async
            'App\Message\Sms': async_sms
```

Basically, I have define the default configuration to force to retry when it fails.

This is my Message object (very basic implementation) :

```
namespace App\Message;

class Sms
{
    /**
     * @param string $content
     * @param int $addresseeId
     * @param int $companyDivisionId
     */
    public function __construct(
        private string $content,
        private int $addresseeId,
        private int $companyDivisionId
    )
    {}

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent(): string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAddresseeId(): int
    {
        return $this->addresseeId;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCompanyDivisionId(): int
    {
        return $this->companyDivisionId;
    }
}
```

This is my MessageHandler (call the manager which use the web service & Doctrine service):

```
class SmsHandler
{
    /**
     * @param UserRepository $userRepository
     * @param CompanyDivisionRepository $companyDivisionRepository
     * @param OvhClientManager $ovhClientManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        private UserRepository $userRepository,
        private CompanyDivisionRepository $companyDivisionRepository,
        private OvhClientManager $ovhClientManager
    ) {}

    /**
     * @param Sms $sms
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke(Sms $sms): void
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $sms->getAddresseeId()]);
        $companyDivision = $this->companyDivisionRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $sms->getCompanyDivisionId()]);
        $this->ovhClientManager->sendSms($sms->getContent(), $user, $companyDivision);
    }
}
```

Do you have an explanation about this problem ?

Comment: I think you have to implement `failure_transport`